# SonarQube + Jacoco Coverage Discrepancies

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, jacoco

I have been using Jacoco to analyze the Code-Coverage of my team's maven project for almost 3 months now. It has been analyzing and increasing properly as we add more and more tests and everything has been working well.

In the last few days we have begun trying to set up a SonarQube analysis of the project. The issue we are running into is that the coverage shown in SonarQube is drastically different from what Jacoco is displaying for us.

I have looked into this already, and read about some of the solutions online, the problem that seemed most similar to what we were running into can be found at the URL [here](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/different-code-coverage-from-jacoco-and-sonarqube/2166/2). But this did not fix the problems we had.

In our `pom.xml` file we are working on, I have added in the properties folder these lines:

```
<sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>./codeCoverage/jacoco.xml</sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
<sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
<sonar.java.source>8</sonar.java.source>
<sonar.java.libraries>target</sonar.java.libraries>
```

which are what I have found online telling us how to configure the SonarProperties.

I am not getting any errors, but the code coverage is different.

For example in the Jacoco.html file, we have a branch coverage of `9.44%` but in SonarQube the conditional coverage is `10.00%`.

The same issues happen with the line coverage which is in Jacoco.html `13.76%` as opposed to `11.1%` in SonarQube.

Comment: Total values are the sums of individual values, so navigate in both reports from project to modules, then to files, where all lines highlighted - this will allow you to isolate problem and if not understand/solve by yourself then at least update this question with https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and detailed screenshots like https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/806#issuecomment-455308196 Otherwise you're simply asking others to waste their time on random guesses.

Comment: @Godin I figured it out, it was not a problem with Jacoco, but within SonarQube their coverage report was pointing to a directory for analysis that did not only contain our Java code. Once I went into the directory the coverage more closely lined up. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I was able figure out what was wrong with the setup that we were using, by looking through our SonarQube analysis deeper and comparing package by package what was being analyzed.

SonarQube was analyzing the whole repository, and the default report for coverage that was displayed was reflecting using not only the `jacoco.xml` but also looking at some code from other types.

To see the accurate code coverage, I had to change where we were looking in SonarQube's analysis, to the directory which housed the Java code exclusively thus aligning the coverage percentages between the two services.

Comment: Hi Zachary, can you please explain more about your solution, I am facing now the same problem!